# how to check all validation on my textfield in swift with textfield() function

Tags: swift

so I have a problem I want to check validation of my textfield If the validation already correct, the button will be enabled and if the validation is not correct the button will be disabled. the problem is If I already pass one validation of one textfield and want to move to another textfield.The validation only check validation where the textfield I click.If I not correct the validation and go to another textfield the button should be disabled and If i correct the validation of another textfield the button will be enabled.I want to the check all validation all of my textfields

email in my code is an optional

here is my code

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let set = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")

    // Casting String as NSString to be able to replace characters using NSRange easily.
    guard let text = textField.text as NSString? else { return true }

    // Get the length of the final text
    let finalTextCount = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string).count

    // Setup the text count for the field depending on which one was edited
    let nomorTextFieldCount = textField == nomorTextField ? finalTextCount :
        nomorTextField.text!.count

    let emailTextFieldCount = textField == emailTextFeild ? finalTextCount :
        emailTextFeild.text!.count
    if let floatingLabelTextField = textField as? SkyFloatingLabelTextField {
        nomorTextField.tag=1
        emailTextFeild.tag=2


        if textField.tag==1{

            if nomorTextFieldCount == 0 {
                floatingLabelTextField.errorMessage = "Nomor can't empty"
                nextButton.isEnabled = false

            }else if nomorTextFieldCount < 10   {
                floatingLabelTextField.errorMessage = "Nomor can't less than  10"
                nextButton.isEnabled = false

            }else if (nomorTextFieldCount > 12 ) {
                floatingLabelTextField.errorMessage = "Nomor can't more than 12"
                nextButton.isEnabled = false

            }
```

Comment: make a class that is inehrited with your textfield, overide one method validate and do your validation isnide it for each textfiled

Comment: I notice that you have made multiple accounts with the same name to repeat post questions.

Comment: You can take one variable val_Count and when validation of your one TF is success increase it by one...when your val_Coount == NO. of TF then enable button otherwise disable it.